# Best practice to make a unique random also secure token in PHP?

Tags: php, security

I know that we have some secure functions in PHP that makes cryptographically secure random bytes like

```
try {
    $token = random_bytes(32);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //error
}
```

But what is the best practice to make it unique?

For example below code can be an acceptable approach ?

```
uniqid('', true).random_bytes(32);
```

With the best.

Comment: *"But what is the best practice to make it unique?"* ... Consider revising your question with an actual use case.

Comment: Colliding a 32byte/256bit random value is hilariously unlikely. Consider it unique.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.random-randomizer.php and there are also packages for UUID generation.

Comment: @Sammitch In fact I checked my database table (that had been created two years ago) and found two same value! So I decided to add some string to the output of this function.